# bootstrap navbar always collapsed but when expanded, need to show the width as it is shown when the screen width is shorter

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar, bootstrapping

I did the following to make my navigation bar always collapsed.  However, when you click on it, it's taking up the whole width of the screen.  And when you click on `Menu`, the dropdown is occupying a small part only.

[image]

What I want is when I click the navigation icon in the right, it will expand but will not take the whole width of the screen.  Instead I want it to display as it displays when the screen width is small just like in the picture

[image]

```
@media (max-width: 2000px) {
    .navbar-header {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-left,.navbar-right {
        float: none !important;
    }
    .navbar-toggle {
        display: block;
    }
    .navbar-collapse {
        border-top: 1px solid transparent;
        box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255,255,255,0.1);
    }
    navbar-fixed-top {
        top: 0;
        border-width: 0 0 1px;
    }
    .navbar-collapse.collapse {
        display: none!important;
    }
    .navbar-nav {
        float: none!important;
        margin-top: 7.5px;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li {
        float: none;
    }
    .navbar-nav>li>a {
        padding-top: 10px;
        padding-bottom: 10px;
    }
    .collapse.in{
        display:block !important;
    }
}
```

This is what I need:
[image]

Comment: It's like you have a menu within a menu. Can you post all of your code or create a [Bootply](http://bootply.com/new) to demonstrate?

Comment: Here it is.. http://www.bootply.com/NSwGH41D7H

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I'm still not sure why you want a menu inside a menu, but you could use a `nav` instead of a `dropdown` if you're looking for full width. The dropdown has a width of 160px. Use `collapse` to show/hide the submenu.

```
<a href="#" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu1" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-hamburger" aria-hidden="true"></span>
    <span>Menu</span>
</a>
<ul class="nav collapse" aria-labelledby="menu" id="menu1">
    <li>
        <div class="menu-content">
            <ul class="nav nav-stacked">
                <li><a href="#">Item1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item3</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Item4</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

http://bootply.com/cv3l6gxjZn

Comment: first, i'm not looking for full width. my problem is if i view it on desktop and click the menu icon, it shows below "Menu" and "Others" in full width, but when you click the "Menu", the items under it are shown in shorter width. what i need is, when i click the menu icon, it should show below "Menu" and "Others" in a shorter width occupying only a portion to the right, not the whole screen width, since my menu icon is on the right, then when you click "Menu" it should show the items as what you saw when you view it on, say, phone screen.

Comment: Sorry, still doesn't make sense to me. How about posting an image that shows what you want.

Comment: i updated the pictures above. what i need is even if i am viewing in the desktop, the menu should not occupy the whole width since my menu icon is on the right only. I updated the colouring in the image to clearly show how i want the menu dropdown to look like when viewed in desktop.  as you can see it's the same as if you're viewing it in phone screen.